# Windows Server 2008 Remote Desktop - Error 9003 - Desktop Windows Manager

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop

One of my users cannot connect the remote desktop this morning.

He enters his login/pass and gets back to the login screen again. He enters his login/pass a second time and then it works...

In the event log, I get this :

```
Log Name:      Application  
Source:        Desktop Window Manager  
Date:          14/12/2009 09:41:45 AM  
Event ID:      9003  
Task Category: None  
Level:         Information  
Keywords:      Classic  
User:          username  
Computer:      servername  
Description:  
The Desktop Window Manager was unable to start because a composited theme is not in use.
```

Server : Windows Server 2008 Standard 32bits
Client : <strike>Windows XP SP3 32 bits</strike> XP/Vista

**Edit :** It's the same problem for all the clients !

Any clue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunantly, Windows Server 2008 has no support for themes over TS. As the Desktop Window Manager (DWM) is turned off when a TS connection is started. The client version / RDP settings does not matter.

You should login to that account locally (not though RDP) and disable any themes.

Comment: You can enable themes by enabling it under Features, called Desktop Experience, and then set the Themes service to start automatically

Comment: I'm not a Pro in Windows servers, looks like you're right. That can be a solution by the way :)